# find North: mathematic explanation

Tags: geometry

Find North with an analog watch is well known:
- short hand pointing at the sun
- cutting angle between the hand and 12 o'clock
- mid point gives the South

but could someone explain the theory ?

Comment: Needs some modification south of the Tropic of Cancer.

Comment: Here's a nice page about the path of the sun in the sky: "[The simple geometry of sun, moon, and star paths](http://notesfromnoosphere.blogspot.com/2012/05/simple-geometry-of-sun-paths.html)". Observe that the procedure is only an approximation unless you're exactly at the North Pole. (And if you are, you probably don't really need to find North...)

Comment: Very good info !

Answer (score 4):

At 12 o'clock the sun is towards south. But the sun makes a complete turn in 24 hours, while the short hand takes 12 hour... so if you keep fixed the clock you will see the sun be (approximately) in the midpoint between the short hand and 12 o'clock. So if you rotate the clock so that the short hand is towards the sun, the midpoint will be south.